# Extract Pieces of innerHTML into Groupings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xml, sorting

I have a string of html and I'm trying to extract different pieces and put into groups. For example:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="filters-container">
<div class="search-filter" id="search-filter-type"><span class="filter-option-title">Car Type</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="filter-types-all" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            <label id="filter-types-all" for="filter-types-all"><span class="filter-label" title="All Car Types">All Car Types</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-1" value="ECAR,CCAR,CDAR,EDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-1"><span class="filter-label" title="Small Cars">Small Cars</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-2" value="ICAR,SCAR,ICAH,IDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-2"><span class="filter-label" title="Medium Cars">Medium Cars</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-3" value="FCAR,PCAR,FDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-3"><span class="filter-label" title="Large Cars">Large Cars</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-4" value="IFAR,SFAR,CFAR,FFAR,RFAR,PFAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-4"><span class="filter-label" title="SUVs &amp; Crossovers">SUVs &amp; Crossovers</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-5" value="MVAR,RVAR,FVAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-5"><span class="filter-label" title="Vans">Vans</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-6" value="LCAR,LDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-6"><span class="filter-label" title="Luxury">Luxury</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-7" value="STAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-7"><span class="filter-label" title="Convertibles">Convertibles</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-8" value="SSAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-8"><span class="filter-label" title="Sports">Sports</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-9" value="ICAH" />
            <label for="filter-types-9"><span class="filter-label" title="Hybrids">Hybrids</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-10" value="SKAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-10"><span class="filter-label" title="Commercial">Commercial</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-11" value="XXAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-11"><span class="filter-label" title="Specialty">Specialty</span></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="search-filter" id="search-filter-payment-type"><span class="filter-option-title">Payment Type</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-pay-now" value="Y" checked="checked" />
            <label for="filter-pay-now"><span class="filter-label" title="Pay Now"><span class="label">Pay Now</span></span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-pay-later" value="N" checked="checked" />
            <label for="filter-pay-later"><span class="filter-label" title="Pay at Pick-up"><span class="label">Pay at Pick-up</span></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When looking at element's innerHTML, I'd like to move all elements with id "filter-types-*" into types array (specifically, the `li` tag). I'm not sure of the best way to approach this. Any help is very much appreciated!

The innerHTML string is `$(xml).find("filters")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: A solution can be to use jQuery to select all elements with class "type" then loop through those elements and push the text to an array variable names typeArray or similar.

Comment: If this is HTML it's invalid. `input` elements do not have a closing tag, not do they have text. They have a `value` attribute.

Comment: @AndrewLohr If the string is located in $(xml).find("filters")[0].innerHTML ...what is the syntax to select all elements with class "type"?

Comment: @Michael is the HTML you posted in your question the result of `$(xml).find("filters")[0].innerHTML` ?

Comment: @AndrewLohr I just updated my post with an actual result of the innerHTML

Comment: This is a very different task than it was a minute ago.

Comment: Sorry ... I was trying to simplify the question originally

Comment: What is your expected output exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using jquery, you could loop over each input in your div (to which I've added an ID to make it easier to target) and push in to the appropriate array using an if (or a switch statement if you plan on adding more).

## Update

I have updated this to reflect your updated question.

```js
var types = [];

var html = $(".search-filter").find("li");

$.each(html, function(){
  var inputs = $(this).find("input");
  
  $.each(inputs, function(){
   if($(this).prop("id").indexOf("filter-types") >= 0){
      types.push($(this).parents("li"));
    } 
  })
})

console.log("Types");
console.log(types);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-filter" id="search-filter-type"><span class="filter-option-title">Car Type</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="filter-types-all" name="filter-types-all" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            <label id="filter-types-all" for="filter-types-all"><span class="filter-label" title="All Car Types">All Car Types</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-1" value="ECAR,CCAR,CDAR,EDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-1"><span class="filter-label" title="Small Cars">Small Cars</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-2" value="ICAR,SCAR,ICAH,IDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-2"><span class="filter-label" title="Medium Cars">Medium Cars</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-3" value="FCAR,PCAR,FDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-3"><span class="filter-label" title="Large Cars">Large Cars</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-4" value="IFAR,SFAR,CFAR,FFAR,RFAR,PFAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-4"><span class="filter-label" title="SUVs &amp; Crossovers">SUVs &amp; Crossovers</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-5" value="MVAR,RVAR,FVAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-5"><span class="filter-label" title="Vans">Vans</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-6" value="LCAR,LDAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-6"><span class="filter-label" title="Luxury">Luxury</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-7" value="STAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-7"><span class="filter-label" title="Convertibles">Convertibles</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-8" value="SSAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-8"><span class="filter-label" title="Sports">Sports</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-9" value="ICAH" />
            <label for="filter-types-9"><span class="filter-label" title="Hybrids">Hybrids</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-10" value="SKAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-10"><span class="filter-label" title="Commercial">Commercial</span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-types-11" value="XXAR" />
            <label for="filter-types-11"><span class="filter-label" title="Specialty">Specialty</span></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="search-filter" id="search-filter-payment-type"><span class="filter-option-title">Payment Type</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-pay-now" value="Y" checked="checked" />
            <label for="filter-pay-now"><span class="filter-label" title="Pay Now"><span class="label">Pay Now</span></span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="filter-pay-later" value="N" checked="checked" />
            <label for="filter-pay-later"><span class="filter-label" title="Pay at Pick-up"><span class="label">Pay at Pick-up</span></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated to now add parent li instead of inputs. Also note, you could probably avoid the double loop by adding `.find('input')` to the initial selector.

Comment: Updated again to now account for all inputs in both `search-filters` - You can add additional if statements and arrays to group the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
//Grab each element with class = "type", iterate them and push into array:
$('.type').each(function(){
    typeArray.push(this);
});

//Grab each element with class = "location", iterate them and push into array:
$('.location').each(function(){
    locationArray.push(this);
}):
```